# Is it possible to use the user_id from one chat bot with other chat app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As I understand the user_id is a page scoped (psid). The question is: If two chatbots that using two app id's, have the same user_id for same users.

If one boot got a message, and after a month I give permissions to the second chatbot: Can I continue the conversation from the second chat bot? Will I be able to use the same user_id's that I collected in my 1st bot?

(I'm not asking about the 24+1 policy)

Comment: Why not just test it?

Comment: From what I tested I saw that it is not the same. But I'm not sure.maybe someone succeeded to get other results,or maybe I tested it wrong.